# Can't import the volley library in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, git

i just got the volley library from the below link..
git clone-https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley
in eclipse i am following steps 
**import>git>project from git>**....etc

and the library got downloaded in C:\Users\active\git\volley

when i just want to import the volley folder to the eclipse(C:\Users\active\git\volley) it shows  "**Select at least one project**" in IMPORT PROJECT.and their is only one project though i have selected that still it shows the same error on the top..seriously need a help...thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to build the jar and then add it to your libs folder in your project.

**How to build the jar:**

```
$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley
$ cd volley
$ android update project -p .
$ ant jar
```

[source](http://karanbalkar.com/2014/05/tutorial-81-using-volley-networking-library-in-android/)

Here is a YouTube video if that would help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5bwn7DYt2AI

You can also [download a non-official build on maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.mcxiaoke.volley).

**Edit:**

It looks like volley can't be built with ant anymore (correct me if I'm wrong). All I did was create a new Android Project, mark it as a library project, create package com.android.volley, copy the source over to the project, and build it.

Comment: +1 for the edit part. I tried to create a new project as mentioned in edit part and build that. Then added that as a lib to my project successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the project name is already exists in your workspace.

Comment: no @Divya...it shows the same at very first when i imported..!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Right Click any project and click on `properties`.
2. Look at the directory of current `WorkSpace` under `location`.
3. Delete any existing copies of Volley or project with the similar name.
4. Re-import Volley.

Comment: @mjosh...yes i deleted that already existed volley library...and tried.got the same error...finally solved with james's solution..